# Problems making a background color through a main.css

Tags: css, html

I Tried changing the background color of the website via main.css. It didn't work. here's a screenshot of the editor (sublime text 3) and the folder I saved the files.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

The other functions all work and the line

```
<head><title>My Website</title>
    <link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```

is the same in every page. Maybe the mistake's somewhere inside there.

Comment: Your css file is in a folder called `css`, not in a folder called `styles`. Fix you `href` and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Always double-check your links. It's more or less one of the most missed mistakes ever. Make sure that the path is correct. It should be `/css/main.css` instead of `/styles/main.css`

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
body{
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

put it in your main.css

U can also apply background-color attribute to any element having a class or an id just like this:

```
.element{
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

if 'element' name is a class or:

```
#element{
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

if 'element' is name of ID

Answer (score 0):

Because you mentioned you are new, is your css located in a folder called "styles"?

If so, you're main.css should contain:

```
body{
background-color: rgb(200,100,0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned you are new to web development, have you tried emptying the browser cache? Sometimes when css doesn't update it is because it has been cached.  Short command on PC: Ctrl+shift+delete, on mac it is cmd+shift+r

Answer (score 0):

Just change:

```
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

to:

```
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```